# How to rename nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, project, package.json

Whenever I start my nodejs project, it refers to itself by the old name I gave it:

> **gpio-editor**@0.0.0 start /home/pi/RPi-Computer-Power/RPi-Server

I do not want it to be called gpio-editor anymore, but I have not found a way to change it on the interwebs. I am pretty new to nodejs, and I didn't originally make this project.

If someone knows how to do this, please let me know. Thanks, Neil

Comment: package.json -> name?

Comment: Aah!! Yes, that is it. I didn't know that existed. Add as an answer for resolution credit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out `package.json`. There should be a few properties in there that you can change (you want to change the name). A simple file would look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "gpio-editor",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "author": "Sudo Programmer <hi@sudoprogrammer.com>",
    "description": "i use this to edit stuff",
    "license": "pick one",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        // something or other, don't include comments though
    }
}
```

After that you should run `npm install`, which will update the file `package-lock.json` accordingly.

**Edit (5/31/2018)**

Since Node 5 (I believe), the `package-lock.json` file has been generated and used as an, "I last built this codebase using these dependency versions" tool. The `package.json` file is *supposed* to do this, but it doesn't protect you from packages that don't follow semantic versioning. For this reason, I would recommend checking the `package-lock.json` file in and updating the name there as well. There's some good info on the lock file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5).

Comment: What if there is a `package-lock.json` ? Should the name be manually changed there also?

Comment: I would. The `package-lock.json` is essentially a, "I built this project with these versions of my dependencies." That is what `package.json` is for, but the lock file will protect you from packages that don't abide by semantic versioning. You should also be checking your lock file into your repo (this will help other users run the code as you have).

Answer (score 5):

Edit the `name` attribute in your `package.json`, that's what determines the name of your package.

Answer (score 3):

if you're copying files from an existing project and still having issues after updating the `name` attribute in `package.json`, try removing `node_modules` dir and `package-lock.json` file (backup if needed) and run `npm i` or `yarn`.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want to change it **via CLI**, you can use the following command:

```bash
npm pkg set name="gpio-editor-new"
```

Reference - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-pkg

Comment: I would have excepted npm to update package-lock.json when changing the package name via CLI. However, that did not happen. So I had to do an additional `npm i --package-lock-only` to update the package-lock.json, too.