# When to use package-lock.json and shrinkwrap.json

Tags: json, node.js

[Should package-lock.json also be published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546718/should-package-lock-json-also-be-published)

[What is the difference between npm-shrinkwrap.json and package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258235/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-shrinkwrap-json-and-package-lock-json)

After reading the above one question remains. When to use what where.

When writing a node module which ***will be*** published to the npm lifecycle (so others can npm install it), `shrinkwrap.json` should be used, since it can be *published*.

When writing a node module which you will use in prodution for your company etc., which ***will not be*** published to the npm lifecycle, `package-lock.json` should be used.

Tbh reading the other questions might give people insight in the mechanics, but for those who want a simple view of how to use them, I must ask this straight forward question.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jpospisil.com/2017/06/02/understanding-lock-files-in-npm-5.html

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate because my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132512/1709587 (which was added there *after* Karl asked here - he did nothing wrong by asking) directly addresses the question of which file to use when. As such, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44258235/1709587 has effectively become a duplicate of this question in the time since it was asked.