# What's the issue in publishing package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

I read use of `package-lock.json` from 
blog
 https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8 
and documentation
 https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

However, its not clear, why its not allowed to publish `package-lock.json` or what problem might occur. May someone throw some light.

Thank you

Comment: package-lock.json is more like a temperory file and may change so why would you want to publish that

Comment: I understand it represents exact state of our project, why are you calling it temporary file?

Comment: "like a temporary" file means that it will be specific to when where and what you are running with your node app. Its actually not required if you publish you app to npm.

Comment: Good point Arpit, but why would we see it as non required when it provide more accurate state of our project, apart from package.json

Comment: @ArpitSolanki It isn't temporary at all, you're even meant to check it into source-control. Are you thinking of a "lock file" used in databases and such? Do not confuse the two, `package-lock.json` is not a lock file.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Should package-lock.json also be published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546718/should-package-lock-json-also-be-published) and [Do I commit the package-lock.json file created by npm 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)

I believe that you refer to

> One key detail about package-lock.json is that it cannot be published

on https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json.

`package-lock.json` indeed will be ignored if published on NPM but `package-lock.json` is intended to be committed to source control.
It ensures that `dependencies` you used on a local machine will be the same versions on a production environment.
You do not want to have `devDependencies` in `package-lock.json` though as they might and will affect production environment.

Comment: gist of your answer is, there is dev dependency in lock file which should not be published, but dev dependency is in package file as well.

Comment: i had read both answers on SO, raised this question for we need direct and helping questions, those questions do not answer requested thing

Answer (score 0):

The reason they shouldn't be published is because it won't do anything. `npm` will ignore any `package-lock.json` that is not at the root of the project as it doesn't make sense to lock dependencies anywhere other than in the project itself.

There's no danger of anything going wrong, it's just pointless to publish it.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json

> The difference is that package-lock.json is that it cannot be published, and it will be ignored if found in any place other than the root project.

Comment: If there's no danger of anything going wrong then why do we need a lock file at all?

Comment: Lock files are used inside npm *projects* to lock specific versions of dependencies. We are talking about publishing an npm module, which will then itself be consumed by npm projects, which is something completely different.

Comment: But it means that if two different projects reference the same module version then they can still be running different code.