# Why do Node modules go into .staging folder?

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json

I have an Electron app that I'm trying to install node modules for. When I run `npm install`, it creates the `node_modules` folder but all the modules go into a subfolder called `.staging`. Each module also has `-xxxxx` appended to it, where the x's are some random alphanumerics.

Other Electron apps I've created have never done this. All the node modules sit in the root of `node_modules` and don't have `-xxxxx` appended.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 65):

I was also facing the same issue, I tried the steps below:

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Delete Node Modules folder
3. Try installing it using below command (should be in open network)

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Note: - ".staging" means, those dependencies are getting downloaded so for the temporary basis it keeps all those dependencies under ".staging" folder. Once all gets downloaded properly then it will showcase them under node_modules only.

I hope this will work.

Comment: apparently in windows we cant have folder name starting with dot (.) ... I starting my project in ubuntu and then moved to windows so I was facing this '.stagging' folder issue,  deleting package-lock.json solved it...

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 51):

This only happens temporarily until the modules are downloaded and installed.  Node seems to do this so it can place together common submodules from all the modules you are installing so it can better structure the node modules folder(mainly for windows users).

If this is happening after an npm install finishes it is likely that there is something wrong with your node installation or something in the install failed.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to apply in my case. This happens for one Electron app. It doesn't happen on any of the others. The issue isn't the NPM installation.

Comment: I have seen this happen many times watching the file tree during an npm install.  Watch another projects install and see if you can see it happen.  Also is it an electron app with a 2 package.json structure? https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Two-package.json-Structure

Comment: If you are using NVM you could try another version of node

Comment: It's worth noting that `preinstall` scripts run in the `.staging` directory while `postinstall` scripts run in the actual target directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you're automatically installing node_modules using CI/CD you should check out [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html). Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5) Stackoverflow question.

```
npm ci
```

The documentation points out the differences between `npm install` and `npm ci`.

- The project must have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`
- If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
- `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
- If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install. This is nice, because it prevents having to do something like `rm -rf node_modules`.
- It will never write to `package.json` or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Answer (score 5):

.staging is a temporary npm folder, where the modules are temporarily saved while they are being downloaded, if the package.json downloads are still not completed, the created folder remains, until the installation is complete.

The problem may be lack of space on your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

I was having 2 versions of node installed on my system. 
`nodejs v4.2` and `node v8.6`

I thought this could be conflicting, so I deleted `nodejs v4.2` with following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

and linked the path with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Again I ran `npm install` and it got fixed

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete package.lock.json
2. Delete node_modules
3. run `npm update`

Comment: Explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
I moved the project from C drive to other drive and ran the following commands
take a backup of older node modules if you are running this and existing project

```
npm cache clean --force
npm update
```

Comment: npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and tried the above answers but it did'nt worked for me; 
I followed below steps to resolve this issue-

1.`npm audit`

By running npm audit I got list of pending packages to install-

2.`npm i packagename`

After installing one or two package one by one from list, I used

3.`npm install`

At this time the installation went smooth without any lag or hangup. Hope this help who is facing similar issue :).

Comment: Before the npm audit, package-lock.json should available. For that, you should do npm i --package-lock-only. After you do npm audit.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cache is corrupt and also unremovable.

This fixed the issue I was experiencing.

1. If you are using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. Get the current node version `node --version`
3. `nvm uninstall`  (that version)
4. `nvm install`  (that version)
5. `nvm use`
6. `npm install`

Answer (score -3):

If you have a windows machine where you do not posses Admin rights to it.

Try deleting node_modules and install using `'npm install'` from command line as

**'ADMINISTRATOR'**

It works!

Anyways, it comes down to an open network thing ;)