# Using "npm install" on ionic 4.12 project returns tons of ENOENT errors

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic4

I'm using the following:

- Ionic: 4.12.0
- Node: 10.5.3
- NPM: 6.4.1
- Platform: Win10

I'm cloning a project from a repo on github. Just doing the usual `npm i` to fetch the node_modules package, I expect no issues coming from this. But I'm getting CRAZY quantities of `ENOENT: No such file or directory` warnings, resulting in 0 packages installed.

It goes something like this:

> ```
> 13743 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\database\package.json'
> 13744 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@ionic-native\core-4d421828\decorators\instance-property.metadata.json'
> 13745 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@angular\fire-594cd4d9\bundles\auth-guard.umd.js'
> 13746 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\firebase-node\package.json'
> 13747 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@ionic-native\core-4d421828\decorators\interfaces.metadata.json'
> 13748 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@ionic-native\google-maps-0866cf3a\ngx\index.d.ts'
> 13749 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\firestore\package.json'
> 13750 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\concat.js'
> 13751 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\functions\package.json'
> 13752 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\copy-within.js'
> 13753 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\entries.js'
> 13754 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\every.js'
> 13755 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\codelyzer-c13de8de\angular\styles\cssAst.js'
> 13756 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\storage\package.json'
> 13757 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\fill.js'
> 13758 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@ionic-native\core-4d421828\decorators\common.js.map'
> 13759 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\filter.js'
> 13760 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-compat-07e6aa41\_esm5\observable\dom\ajax.js'
> 13761 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\codelyzer-c13de8de\angular\styles\cssLexer.js'
> 13762 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\angularfire2-f8aad165\auth\index.d.ts'
> 13763 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\core-js-3c812954\es\array\virtual\find-index.js'
> 13764 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\geron\OneDrive\Escritorio\AppElias\node_modules\.staging\@ionic-native\core-4d421828\decorators\cordova-function-override.js.map'
> ...
> ```

It's longer than that. I can post the complete log if needed, I've already tried:

- Reinstalling npm/node/ionic
- Using updated versions of npm/node/ionic
- Using administrator privileges.
- Turning off/uninstalling antivirus software.
- Turning off firewalls.
- Checking if my `.json` packages are wrong.
- Checking if my `.git` is wrong.
- Deleting package-lock.json and using npm i.

I must say this issue is specific to my computer and doesn't happen on coworkers computers. I can't nail the issue, and being incapable of using `npm i` is taxing heavily on my time constraints.

Does anyone know what it might be?

**EDIT 1**
package.json here: https://pastebin.com/7JpUZ4U1

**EDIT 2**
Apparently, it does download some npm files and stores them on node_modules/.staging, i've tried "npm audit" "npm fix" And everything here:

[Why do Node modules go into .staging folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573592/why-do-node-modules-go-into-staging-folder)

No solution yet.

Comment: Can you please give tell witch repo on github?

Comment: It's a private git repo. I can't. But I can give you parts of the code, maybe the package.json?

Comment: Cool, so: did you follow that repo's `README.md` instructions on how to install things?

Comment: Try "npm init" command and "npm install" if error still exists post package.json

Comment: @RaghuramSadineni I tried already, heres the package.json: https://pastebin.com/7JpUZ4U1

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did. The first step is using npm i, that's the issue.

Comment: I googled for `"warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory"` (including the quotes) and found several immediately results all of which sound like they'd solve your problem. Did you search and try any of those (and if you did: [say what you already tried in your post](/help/how-to-ask) so that people won't end up asking you to do things you already tried.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There is a list of things I've tried at the end of my post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Made a new edit. Still trying to fix it.

Comment: does you github repo contain "node_modules" folder inside it?

Comment: It does, it's an ionic project @RaghuramSadineni

Comment: A github repo must not contain node_modules as they differ from system to system,to make you code working clone your project without node_modules and then try others steps like "npm install" and all. Tell the user of git repo to add files by using proper gitignore files to avoid future conflicts

Comment: @RaghuramSadineni My bad, I meant it SHOULD have one after using npm i. The github repo just has the base app folders

Comment: Okay now you got no option left just search for missing packages and install them manually.

Comment: @RaghuramSadineni I would. But npm i isn't working.

Comment: Specify the package name while installing and dont use -g tag Ex:-`npm i @ionic-native`