# Docker build sometimes fail on "file not found or excluded by .dockerignore" for a nested ignored file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, node-modules, docker-build

My directory structure:

```
├── src/
├───── backend/
├─────── Dockerfile
├─────── ...
├───── frontend/
├─────── Dockerfile
├─────── node_modules/
├─────── ...
├───── commons/
├─────── ...
├── .dockerignore
```

`.dockerignore` includes the line `**/node_modules` and my build context is the root directory due to usage of `commons`.

I'm running both

`docker build ... -f src/backend/Dockerfile .`

`docker build ... -f src/frontend/Dockerfile .`

in parallel, and sometimes the `backend` build will fail on the following specific error:

> error checking context: 'file
>   ('/workspace/src/frontend/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-2a6f888f')
>   not found or excluded by .dockerignore'.

From my understanding (see [Why do Node modules go into .staging folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573592/why-do-node-modules-go-into-staging-folder)) the `.staging` folder is temporary and there might be a race condition when walking it (see Docker cli [source](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/image/build/context.go#L50)).

However, why is this file walked in the first place if `node_modules` is ignored? Am I misusing the ignore context functionality or is it an actual race condition?

The issue is reproduced in Google Cloud Build environment, where I'm using docker cli via the image `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`, which uses docker client version `19.03.5` and is run with docker server version `18.09.3`, API version `1.39`.

Comment: first, are both the backend and frontend services use JS? second, please add your Dockerfile so we could get more context to the Dockerfile running process

Answer (score 0):

Clean your system.

```
docker system prune -a
```

Note this will remove also all images not used in a container.

Comment: This happened in build machine, unlikely that's the issue

Comment: I do that by a cronjob every night on my Jenkinsmachines. In my case for space on device issues. But had sometimes similar issues with docker build.