# Does package-lock.json need to be versioned in git?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, package, gitignore

npm 5 & nodejs 8 introduces a file named **package-lock.json**, I want to know if it is need to be versioned or be ignored in git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I commit the package-lock.json file created by npm 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)

Answer (score 14):

**Short Answer :** Yes It must be.

**Long Answer :**

As Per [npmjs Documentaion](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) :

> `package-lock.json` is automatically generated for any operations
>   where npm modifies either the `node_modules` tree, or `package.json`.
>   It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent
>   installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of
>   intermediate dependency updates.
>
> **This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and serves various purposes**:
>
> - Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to
>     install exactly the same dependencies.
> - Provide a facility for users to `time-travel` to previous states of `npm_modules` without having to commit the directory itself.
> - To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source control diffs.
> - And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

Comment: @henry-leu, did this answered your question ?