# Upgrading React library version: is it advisable to push only package.json or to push package.json and package-lock.json both?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

While upgrading React library version is it advisable to push only package.json or to push package.json and package-lock.json both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push both, no matter what you are upgrading. It is always recommended to push both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` into your source control. According to the [npm docs on package-lock.json](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v5.0.0/doc/files/package-lock.json.md): *(Bolding added by me)*

> `package-lock.json` is automatically generated for any operations where
>   npm modifies either the `node_modules` tree, or `package.json`. It
>   describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent
>   installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of
>   intermediate dependency updates.
>
> **This file is intended to be committed into source repositories**, and
>   serves various purposes:
>
> - Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that
>     teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to
>     install exactly the same dependencies.
> - Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of
>     node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
> - To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable
>     source control diffs.
> - And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated
>     metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210813/8620945) for more information and discussion.

Comment: Thanks alot! its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

both,
 because all packege.json module version are similar to package-lock.json

Comment: no it's not same! package-lock.json has specific versions whereas package.json has versions with ~ and ^ which gives us flexibility to update package to recent minor version or major version respectively

Comment: yes you are write but when i  update the version on package.json any depandency  on third party it's also update the similar version of package-lock.json