# Angular app in nginx not refreshing (cache problem)

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, caching

I'm serving my angular 17 application via nginx. The problem is that new features / changes to the angular app are not displayed until i do a hard refresh in my browser.

I've already checked if output hashing is correctly enabled for my build in angular.json, which does not seem to be the problem.

I also do not see a problem with my nginx.conf. I also thought about my ngsw service worker as a culprit.

What else could it be?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM <docker-hub-mirror>/library/node:20.11-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
USER root

COPY . .

# Install needed node packages
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685701
RUN npm ci && npm run build

USER 1000

# Serve application via nginx
FROM <docker-hub-mirror>/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.20.1-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/security-headers.conf /etc/nginx/snippets/security-headers.conf

# Copy build
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_tokens off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/security-headers.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    server {
        server_name localhost;
        listen 4200;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location ~ /index.html|.*\.json$ {
            expires -1;
            include /etc/nginx/snippets/security-headers.conf;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
                proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }

        location ~ .*\.css$|.*\.js$ {
            include /etc/nginx/snippets/security-headers.conf;
            add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=31449600'; # one year
        }

        location / {
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri /index.html;
            include /etc/nginx/snippets/security-headers.conf;
            add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=86400'; # one day
        }
    }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "appx": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true,
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": true
        }
      },
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "src/polyfills.ts"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon-32x32.png",
              "src/favicon-96x96.png",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/@censored/core/dist",
                "output": "."
              },
              "src/silent-renew.html"
            ],
            "styles": ["src/style-wrapper.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["node_modules/"]
            },
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "serviceWorker": "src/ngsw-config.json",
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              }
            },
            "iat": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.iat.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "IDA:build:production"
            },
            "iat": {
              "buildTarget": "IDA:build:production"
            },
            "dev": {
              "buildTarget": "IDA:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "IDA:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "IDA:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon-32x32.png",
              "src/favicon-96x96.png",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/@censored/core",
                "output": "."
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["node_modules/"]
            },
            "styles": ["src/style-wrapper-webpack.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "exclude": ["e2e/**/*"],
            "polyfills": ["src/polyfills.ts", "zone.js", "zone.js/testing", "@angular/localize/init"],
            "sourceMap": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html", "e2e/**/*.ts"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics"],
    "cache": {
      "enabled": true,
      "environment": "all"
    },
    "schematics": {
      "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
        "setParserOptionsProject": true
      },
      "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
        "setParserOptionsProject": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ngsw-config.json:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/*.js", "/manifest.webmanifest"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**", "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```