# my git is not managing my package.json file

Tags: git

I think I don't understand git and how to manage my package.json.

I have an older .Net Core 2.0 project that I am upgrading slowly to .Net 6.  I have a git branch for this called `newPlanGameUpgrade`.  In that branch, I had to remove a package in my package.json called `aspnet-webpack` because it's not compatiable with .Net 6.

So I did that, and got everything working in that branch.

But now, I just switched back to master to check something like this:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

I cleaned and rebuilt the solution, but I still get this error:

> NodeInvocationException: Webpack dev middleware failed because of an
> error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find
> module 'aspnet-webpack'

So I am guessing that git doesn't save different versions of package.json?

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to run `npm install` again every time your `package.json` changes

Comment: git manages whatever files you tell it to manage (by running `git add`) and doesn't bother you about changes to whatever files you tell it to ignore (in a file called `.gitignore`)

Comment: @IMSoP oh ok thanks, I found my `.gitignore` file and see that `package-lock.json` is listed.  Should I delete that?  thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210813/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+package-lock.json+commit

Comment: @mousetail I think that will cause issues though because the version of package.json I have now for .Net 6 is different than the old version of .Net Core 2.

Comment: Git knows nothing about json and does not "manage" json files in any special way. Git will store the file's content the way it stores any other file's content; if you need something more than that, use a program other than Git to do that.