# git ignore commited files on a PUBLIC branch

Tags: git

it seems there are already "simlilar" answers, but my situation is

- I'm working on a public branch with many teammates
- file "a.txt" was commited and pushed
- I add "a.txt" in `.gitignore`
- I run `git rm --cached a.txt`
- and "a.txt" does been ignored in my local branch, then I push it
- but seems my teammates keep pushing this file back, everytime I pull from remote, "a.txt" is not ignored

so should I ask all my teammates to run `git rm --cached a.txt` in their local branch?

(a.txt is the classic "package-lock.json", due to diff versions among local machines and servers)

Comment: A file that is in a commit will be copied to Git's index by any action that checks out that commit. Once the file is in Git's index, it's no longer an *untracked file* and cannot be ignored. It can only become untracked again by removing the file from Git's index (using `git rm` for instance, or by checking out some other commit in which the file *does not* exist).

Comment: In short, only untracked files can be ignored. Your method (of removing it) works to achieve this. That won't make *other people* remove *their* version. And, as other answers noted, package-lock.json should not be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are adding `a.txt` back. If you also add `.gitignore` and push, then they probably won't add it again.

Note: `package-lock.json` is intended to be included in source control. See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)