# Is package-lock.json file important? How do you add the file package-lock.json to gitignore?

Tags: git, commit, gitignore

I need to add `package-lock.json` to gitignore before doing a commit. How do I do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I commit the package-lock.json file created by npm 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5)

Answer (score 5):

It's not a wise decision to make, package-lock.json or yarn.lock is important to build the same dependencies tree you used when you build on your project, so please **don't delete** it **or ignore** it in your git workflow

Anyhow to ignore any file in git, just add a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project(with a dot at first) and add any file/folder path(relative to the root directory), or any globe pattern you like(e.g assets/*.mp4)

for example to ignore `node_modules` folder and all `.gif` files in your assets folder, add the following to your `.gitignore` file

```
node_modules

assets/*.gif
```