# Git: Switching branches creates modified DLLs in working directory which cannot be undone

Tags: git, visual-studio

My Visual Studio solution includes a \packages\ subfolder for NuGet packages.
Yesterday, I switched from Branch A to Branch B. I did nothing. No modifications. I then quickly switched back to Branch A.

Suddenly Git showed a bunch of DLLs files as modified in Branch A. All of them from the packages subfolder.
I did not make any changes on either branch.
Naturally, I tried to undo these changes with `git reset --hard` but that did not work. They stayed in my working directory as Changed files. I also tried to undo them through Visual Studio, but again same problem.

How do I force undo these changes?

Comment: Does `git status` from the command line show the same files as modified, as those you see in VS? If yes, try deleting all those files, and then `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Side note, usually you don't want to track those files in your code repo.

Comment: Are you using Git LFS for these DLLs?

Comment: @TTT Yes, git status shows the same files modified as those in VS. I should track those file otherwise the solution won't compile if someone clones the repository.

Comment: If you run `npm` before your build, you only need to checkin the package.json, and perhaps the package-lock.json file so you can just run `npm ci` which will be faster after the first time. This way you don't have to keep tracking all those binaries which can bloat the repository. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56254478/184546)